# A test for missing at random

Tags: hypothesis-testing, missing-data

I have data about locations (Provinces, cities, postal codes, etc).  Some of my postal codes are missing, and I think there may be a relationship between province and the missing postal code.

I can determine the proportion of missing values by taking the quotient of number of missing items divided by total counts for that Province.

Could I test if the data are missing at random by applying a chisquare test?

Here is a sample of the data

```
    Missing Rate
AB  0.12512
BC  0.0325
MB  0.01777
NB  0.0
NL  0.00347
NS  0.06188
NT  0.0
ON  0.05774
PE  0.0
QC  0.02115
SK  0.0
YT  0.0
```

s

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible to know that data are missing at random without seeing the missing data itself.

*Missing at random* is defined to be the conditional independence of the missing data and the "observed data and missingness indcators" given the observed data.  In other words, it says that the missing data tells you nothing new.  But you can't know that they tell you nothing new without seeing them.